# Which R packages have good collections of psychology datasets?

Tags: statistics, data, teaching-of-psychology

The [open source statistical software R](http://www.r-project.org/) has a range of contributed packages. Some of them include datasets.

I teach research methods in psychology and I'm looking for interesting real-world dataset to use as the basis for tutorials. I've found a few in contributed R packages (e.g., [AER](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AER/index.html), [psych](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/index.html)), but I'm not aware of a general resource listing R packages that supply multiple interesting, real-world, psychological datasets. In particular, some textbooks have an aligned R package containing many interesting datasets.

- **What R packages include multiple interesting, real-world, psychological datasets?**
- **For any package identified, it would be good to have a sense of the kinds of datasets contained**

Comment: I'd check the open data section of stackexchange.

Answer (score 9):

Some extremely large personality data sets can be downloaded at http://personality-testing.info/_rawdata/ in CSV format.

They are not packaged in R, but I post the link because you indicate in your reply to USER:what that you are having trouble finding any data sets what so ever.

Comment: Thanks. They look like they'll be useful for a factor analysis / psychometrics lab I need to give.

Answer (score 6):

680 datasets that were originally distributed alongside R and some of its add-on packages are collected on [GitHub](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/). An [index](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html) lists the datasets and the packages they came from.

If you just want datasets and don't mind that they were not part of any R package, then there are many available for free on the web. For example, [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com) lists over 7 million datasets. Google turns up many other collections.

Comment: awesome. I hadn't seen that github resource before. That said, I often have trouble finding authentic and realistic psychological datasets on the web, as opposed to toy-example datasets.

Comment: I think it should be made a requirement to publish the datasets with a journal article (at least if the research was publicly financed).

Answer (score 6):

The [languageR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/languageR/index.html) package contains several interesting real-world datasets relevant to psycholinguistics. These datasets are presumably also described in the [accompanying textbook](http://books.google.com/books/about/Analyzing_Linguistic_Data.html?id=UvWkIg5E4foC).

Answer (score 1):

Not R packages, but:

Best psychological datasets I found on the internet was from the dataverse at Harvard: https://dataverse.harvard.edu

https://osf.io also has good data sets, but the search engine is mediocre. It is usually more convenient to search from google directly.